# What is wrong in this snippet? (Javascript object)

Tags: javascript, object

```js
const address = {
 street: 'Dique 3',
 city: 'Santa Cruz',
 zipcode: 38320,
 function showAddress {
  console.log(`${this.street}, ${this.city}, ${this.zipcode}`)
 }
}

address.showAddress();
```

Comment: [Help Center -> How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The syntax error in the console could give you a hint on what may be wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are add methods the wrong way.

```js
const address = {
 street: 'Dique 3',
 city: 'Santa Cruz',
 zipcode: 38320,
 showAddress(){
  console.log(`${this.street}, ${this.city}, ${this.zipcode}`)
 }
}

address.showAddress();
```

Comment: Thank you!, I'm learning javascript, and I was not sure if I can call properties of an object from within itself. But now I saw I just had some sintax errors.

Comment: @Dedalos01 You can call them inside the method of an object but can't use one property to set another while creating object.